# What is "Subject to frequency limit" tag in Firebase cloud messaging

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, limit, frequency, schedule

[image][image: Firebase screen shot]

What is "Subject to frequency limit" tag in Firebase Cloud Messaging? When I try to schedule the message there is on tag called "Subject to frequency limit", which further has two option

Subject to frequency limit

1. Custom
2. Once per user for this message

What does it actually mean, can anyone please explain? How will this option make difference to my scheduled Cloud messages.

Answer (score 4):

`Once per user for this message`:

Every user will get this notification only once. If there are new users the next day, they will get the notification at the scheduled time. Users that already received that notification e.g. yesterday won't get it again.

---

`Custom`:

Then you can set `Send no more than one message every x days`. That means that every user will get that notification only once in x days.

E.g. if you set it to `1`: Every user gets that notification daily at the scheduled time.